# How to restrict touch movement for android on Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D car racing game for android device. I have coded the touch movement for my car. But the problem is the car is going beyond the track. How can I restrict the car movement, I mean how can I code for my car to stay in the screen (Screen resolution is 480*800 and car sprites max position is 4.2 and min -4.2). Here r my C# car controller script.

```
using UnityEngine; using System.Collections;

public class carController : MonoBehaviour {

     public float carSpeed;


     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

         if (Input.touchCount == 1) {

             Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
             if(touch.position.x < Screen.width/2){
                 transform.position += Vector3.left * carSpeed * Time.deltaTime;


             }
             else if(touch.position.x > Screen.width/2){
                 transform.position += Vector3.right * carSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

             }

         }
     }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate solution will be to use a clamp function like this as you know the max and min values after calculating the desired movement.

```
 void Update () {

     if (Input.touchCount == 1) {

         Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
         if(touch.position.x < Screen.width/2){
             transform.position += Vector3.left * carSpeed * Time.deltaTime;


         }
         else if(touch.position.x > Screen.width/2){
             transform.position += Vector3.right * carSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

         }
         Vector3 position = transform.position;
         position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -4.2f, 4.2f);
         transform.position = position;

     }
 }
```